# Macro help for cutting reports by name

Tags: excel, vba, report

I have the below macro that cuts my report up by name (when it asks me which column to filter on, its 2).

It works perfectly for I need, as it also saves down each cut per person for each report where the report is saved.  However, I also need it to pick up everything by name of person in all other tabs in the report. EG: Dave Smith is on the main summary page, and the below macro cuts it by Dave Smith, and saves that cut down. But Dave Smith also has data in 7/8 other tabs, that also need to be included in the new, saved down cut.

```
Sub parse_data()

    'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets
    'based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
    'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like
    'to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.
    
    Const TITLE_ROW = 1

    Dim wbOut As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim iFilterCol As Integer
    Dim sPath As String
    
    ' get filter column nu,ber
    iFilterCol = Application.InputBox( _
            prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", _
            title:="Filter column", Default:="3", Type:=1)

    If iFilterCol < 1 Then
        MsgBox iFilterCol & " not valid", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iFilterCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dict As Object, key
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' get unique values using dictionary
    For iRow = TITLE_ROW + 1 To iLastRow
        key = Trim(ws.Cells(iRow, iFilterCol))
        If Not dict.exists(key) Then
            dict.Add key, iRow
        End If
    Next
     
    ' create separate workbooks
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each key In dict
    
        ' apply filter
        ws.Rows(TITLE_ROW).AutoFilter Field:=iFilterCol, Criteria1:=key
        
        ' create new workbook
        Set wbOut = Workbooks.Add
        Set wsOut = wbOut.Sheets(1)
        wsOut.Name = key
        ws.Range("A" & TITLE_ROW & ":A" & iLastRow).EntireRow.Copy wsOut.Range("A1")
        wsOut.Columns.AutoFit
        ' save and close
        wbOut.SaveAs (sPath & key & ".xlsx")
        wbOut.Close False
    
    Next
   
    ws.Activate
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox dict.Count & " workbooks created", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Find` to locate the filter column for the other sheets, apply filter and repeat the code for the first sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub parse_data()

    'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets
    'based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
    'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like
    'to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.
    
    Const TITLE_ROW = 1

    Dim wbOut As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet, wsOther As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long, iLastOther As Long
    Dim iFilterCol As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim sPath As String, sSummary As String
    
    ' get filter column nu,ber
    iFilterCol = Application.InputBox( _
            prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", _
            Title:="Filter column", Default:="3", Type:=1)

    If iFilterCol < 1 Then
        MsgBox iFilterCol & " not valid", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' or ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    sSummary = ws.Name
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iFilterCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dict As Object, key
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' get unique values using dictionary
    For iRow = TITLE_ROW + 1 To iLastRow
        key = Trim(ws.Cells(iRow, iFilterCol))
        If Not dict.exists(key) Then
            dict.Add key, iRow
        End If
    Next
     
    ' create separate workbooks
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each key In dict
    
        ' apply filter
        ws.Rows(TITLE_ROW).AutoFilter Field:=iFilterCol, Criteria1:=key
        
        ' create new workbook
        Set wbOut = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' 1 sheet
        Set wsOut = wbOut.Sheets(1)
        wsOut.Name = key
        ws.Range("A" & TITLE_ROW & ":A" & iLastRow).EntireRow.Copy wsOut.Range("A1")
        wsOut.Columns.AutoFit

        ' search other worksheets
        For Each wsOther In wb.Sheets
            If wsOther.Name <> sSummary Then

                'find name to get filter column
                wsOther.AutoFilterMode = False
                Set rng = wsOther.UsedRange.Find(CStr(key), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    iLastOther = wsOther.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                    wsOther.Rows(TITLE_ROW).AutoFilter _
                           Field:=rng.Column, Criteria1:=CStr(key)
   
                    n = wbOut.Sheets.Count
                    Set wsOut = wbOut.Sheets.Add(after:=wbOut.Sheets(n))
                    wsOut.Name = wsOther.Name
                    wsOther.Range("A" & TITLE_ROW & ":A" & iLastOther).EntireRow.Copy _
                      wsOut.Range("A1")
                    wsOut.Columns.AutoFit

               End If
               wsOther.AutoFilterMode = False
           End If
        Next

        ' save and close
        wbOut.SaveAs (sPath & key & ".xlsx")
        wbOut.Close False
    
    Next
    ws.Activate
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox dict.Count & " workbooks created", vbInformation
End Sub
```